# How do i get information that is object sender

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently trying to get access to information that is passed in through an object sender.

The application I am working on is a `winforms` application with a `list view`.
 I want to get the number of the `ListViewItem` that the user has pressed on. 
The `ListView item` that I have pressed on is correct when I debug.

However I am unaware of how to get the information I want from the `object sender`. 
I want to access the `ListViewItem number`,

> look at the posted image **ListViewItem: {24919}** in this case

so I can use this number as index, when I search in a database.

Does anyone have a fast tip so I can continue with my program ?

```
private void InvoiceListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Connect to db and search based on the the listviewItemnumber.
}
```

Currently the object sender containsmethod;

[image]

Comment: `(sender as ListView).WhateverYouWant`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the item selected by casting the `sender` to `ListView` and then get corresponding value as given below:

```cs
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
ListView lw = (ListView)sender;
            
            foreach(ListViewItem lvi in lw.SelectedItems )
            {
                MessageBox.Show(lvi.SubItems[0].Text);
            }
}
```

Comment: This was what i was looking for! Thank you. Unfortunately i cannot uppvote since i have < 15 in rep. When i do i will doe because this helped me.

Answer (score 4):

You can type-check the `sender` and work with the result:

```
private void InvoiceListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is ListView listView)) return;
    //work with the listView object from here:
    listView.Items = ...
}
```

Comment: Side note: we call `sender is ListView listView` and alike constructions *pattern matching*

Comment: That's the word I was looking for! Thanks!